# Aim triangle point towards center of circle while moving

Tags: javascript, html

I want the triangle to aim towards the center at all time while it is spinning as it is right now

```js
var element = document.getElementById('background');
var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
var camera = {};
camera.x = 0;
camera.y = 0;
var scale = 1.0;
var obj = [];
var t = {};
t.angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2; //start angle
t.radius = 200;
t.x = Math.cos(t.angle) * t.radius; // start position x
t.y = Math.sin(t.angle) * t.radius; //start position y
t.duration = 10000; //10 seconds per rotation
t.rotSpeed = 2 * Math.PI / t.duration; // Rotational speed (in radian/ms)
t.start = Date.now();
obj.push(t);

function update() {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var delta = Date.now() - obj[i].start;
    obj.start = Date.now();
    var angle = obj[i].rotSpeed * delta;
    // The angle is now already in radian, no longer need to convert from degree to radian.
    obj[i].x = obj[i].radius * Math.cos(angle);
    obj[i].y = obj[i].radius * Math.sin(angle);
  }
}

function draw() {
  update();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, element.width, element.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(0 - (camera.x - element.width / 2), 0 - (camera.y - element.height / 2));
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    /*Style circle*/
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, obj[i].radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.lineWidth = 60;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();

    //Dot style
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(obj[i].x,obj[i].y,10,0,Math.PI*2);  
    ctx.moveTo(0 + obj[i].x, 0 + obj[i].y);
    ctx.lineTo(75 + obj[i].x, 25 + obj[i].y);
   ctx.lineTo(75 + obj[i].x, -25 + + obj[i].y);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();    
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();  
  }
  ctx.restore();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="background" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Here is a quick fiddle that has all the code already in it just for convenience :)
https://jsfiddle.net/4xwmo5tj/5/

I have already made it spin (the dot is there for now but will be removed later so that can be ignored) the only thing that I still need to do is aim it towards the center at all time. I think I have to use css transform translate for it. but I don't know how to

Comment: Use Math.atan2 to find the angle between 2 points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use **CSS** animations.

```css
.outer-circle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

.inner-cricle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;  
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 6%;
}


@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="triangle"></div><div class="inner-cricle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way you can explain me how the keyframes work? I know a little of it but I actually never used it before

Answer (score 0):

The triangle is not spinning at all. There is just a red dot circle in circumference and triangle inside black circle which is still. So what do you want to do?

Comment: wrong fiddle. updated it. You will see the dot spinning with triangle stuck to it. The idea is that the point of the triangle that is stuck to the dot ALWAYS points towards the center of the circle. I'm trying ctx.rotate(degree) right now. Which seems to work but I can figure out the right formula to get the calculation of the degree

Answer (score 0):

The block of the code responsible for the triangle is under `// Dot Style`. The lines `ctx.lineTo` plot two dots at (x,y) coordinates. I fiddle around with the two coordinates until the triangle was facing down. Below is the end result:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('background');
var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
var camera = {};
camera.x = 0;
camera.y = 0;
var scale = 1.0;
var obj = [];

var t = {};
t.angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2; //start angle
t.radius = 200;
t.x = Math.cos(t.angle) * t.radius; // start position x
t.y = Math.sin(t.angle) * t.radius; //start position y
t.duration = 10000; //10 seconds per rotation
t.rotSpeed = 2 * Math.PI / t.duration; // Rotational speed (in radian/ms)
t.start = Date.now();

obj.push(t);


function update() {

  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var delta = Date.now() - obj[i].start;
    obj.start = Date.now();
    var angle = obj[i].rotSpeed * delta;
    // The angle is now already in radian, no longer need to convert from degree to radian.
    obj[i].x = obj[i].radius * Math.cos(angle);
    obj[i].y = obj[i].radius * Math.sin(angle);
  }
}

function draw() {
  update();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, element.width, element.height);

  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(0 - (camera.x - element.width / 2), 0 - (camera.y - element.height / 2));
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    /*Style circle*/
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, obj[i].radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.lineWidth = 60;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.stroke();

    //Dot style
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(obj[i].x, obj[i].y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.moveTo(0 + obj[i].x, 0 + obj[i].y);
    ctx.lineTo(25 + obj[i].x, -75 + obj[i].y);
    ctx.lineTo(-25 + obj[i].x, -75 + obj[i].y);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
  }

  ctx.restore();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```css
#background {
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="background" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Sorry, I can't provide any more specific details. The Cavas API and drawing are not my turfs.

Comment: Well I know that. But I need the arrowpoint (which is the point of the arrow that is stuck to the dot) to always aim towards the center of the circle. What you show me here is just simply rotating my arrow 45°... No quite what I'm looking for